# Close WooCommerce Product Tabs by default

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

By default Product Tabs in WooCommerce auto opens the first one. Is it possible to have them all closed by default, requiring you to click it to see more?

I have tried the following code, but it does not seem to do it. Perhaps there is a PHP code that does it or something simple?

**I already tried this without luck**:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    var $tabs = jQuery( '.wc-tabs, ul.tabs' ).first();
    $tabs.parent().find('#tab-description').hide();
    $tabs.parent().find( '.tab-title-description' ).removeClass('active');
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** - You should try instead:

```
// Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'close_all_product_tabs' );
function close_all_product_tabs(){
    // Only on single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return;
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#tab-description').hide( function(){
                    $( 'li#tab-title-description' ).removeClass('active');
                });
            }, 200);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

---

> This is an edit specifically to the authors theme structure which is customized:

```
    jQuery(function($){
        jQuery(function($){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#tab-description').hide( function(){
                    $( 'li#description_tab' ).removeClass('active');
                });
            }, 200);
        });
    });
```

---

Now in your theme, there is specifically a `<div>` container for all **your content tabs**, that WooCommerce don't have by default:

```
<div class="tab-panels">
```

This container has a grey border and some padding, so when you hide the description tab, it stays empty like a white flat rectangle with a grey border, which is not very nice. so you should need to hide it or to give him 0 opacity

To hide it You can handle this in many other ways using:

```
- `$('div.tab-panels').addClass('hidden');` and some CSS rules for this 'hidden' class
- `$('div.tab-panels').css('opacity', '0');`
- `$('div.tab-panels').css('visibility', 'hidden');`
```

Once hidden, you will need to make it visible when a button is clicked (and this is the harder part):

```
- `$('div.tab-panels').removeClass('hidden');`
- `$('div.tab-panels').css('opacity', '1');`
- `$('div.tab-panels').css('visibility', 'visible');`
```

The hardest thing will be to get the click event to trigger this…

Comment: I tested the above, but the product tabs are still open by default on my WooCommerce product pages.

Comment: I will mark your answer correct as it may be able to help a lot of other people. It is not working in our setup/theme. If you happen to know any fix for our site I would love to know: http://detitalienskekoekken.dk.linux99.unoeuro-server.com/produkt/gavekort-til-det-italienske-koekken/.

Comment: @eMikkelsen I have simplified the code and added a special section for your theme…