# Keep Woocommerce single product tabs closed in Flatsome theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I have been using [Close WooCommerce Product Tabs by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835218/close-woocommerce-product-tabs-by-default/47835493#47835493) answer code to keep all my product tabs closed on my woocommerce site. I just updated my theme (flatsome) and now this code does not work anymore.

Any suggestions on what do change to get it to work again?

Answer (score 0):

In Flatsome theme, it seems that have changed their html structure on [their single product pages](http://flatsome3.uxthemes.com/shop/men/jeansmaker-tee-lee-jeans/?style=layout-fullscreen-fashion)… So try the following *(lightly updated version)*:

```
// Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'close_all_product_tabs' );
function close_all_product_tabs(){
    // Only on single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return;
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#tab-description').hide( function(){
                    $( 'li.description_tab' ).removeClass('active');
                });
            }, 200);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> **Changed:** `'li#tab-title-description'` to `'li.description_tab'`…